# Why is this the eigenvalue?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

The equation I am looking at (the wave equation for the electric field) has the following form:

$\nabla_t^2\mathcal{E} + [(\frac{\omega}{c})^2n^2(x,y) - \beta^2]\mathcal{E} = 0$

where $\nabla_t^2 = \nabla^2 - \partial^2/\partial z^2$ (the subscript $t$ denotes transverse components of the Laplacian).

The author now says that this equation can be viewed as an eigenvalue problem with $\mathcal{E}$ being the eigenfunctions and $\beta^2$ the eigenvalues.

Shouldn't the eigenvalues be $\beta^2 - (\frac{\omega}{c})^2n^2(x,y)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $n(x,y)$ is not constant, and the eigenvalues should be constant. The eigenvalue problem might be clearer if it is written in the form
$$\left[\nabla_t^2 + \left(\frac{\omega}{c}\right)^2n^2(x,y)\right]\mathcal{E} = \beta^2 \mathcal{E}.$$

The operator whose eigenvalue problem is being considered is $\nabla_t^2 + \left(\frac{\omega}{c}\right)^2n^2(x,y)$, with $\beta^2$ playing the role of the eigenvalue. $n(x,y)$ plays the role of an operator, just as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ do.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense. Thanks! (edit: will accept the answer as soon as StackExchange will let me do it)